# Memcached : How to track keys stored in a Server

Tags: memcached

I am using Xmemcached-1.3.5 configured in two servers , for our high traffic website .

Some snippet of code inside my Application .

```
String location = "localhost:11211,10.1.2.1:11211";
MemcachedClientBuilder builder = new XMemcachedClientBuilder(
AddrUtil.getAddressMap(location));
```

I see that each server acts as a unique Data Store to store the keys , my question is that **is it possible to track , what particular keys are contained in Server 1 and Server 2** ??

Thanks in advnace .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Memcached was not built for that. It uses 2 hash functions (at the client and the server) to avoid storing a reference for every object. That being said, there are few nice tools that dump the Memcached content in an offline manner, see more details [here](http://www.dctrwatson.com/2010/12/how-to-dump-memcache-keyvalue-pairs-fast/)